# How can I get the timestamp of a message in Discord.py?

Tags: python, datetime, object, discord, discord.py

So I have been trying to do a bot, that gets when the message was sent and upload it to a database. I just can't figure this Object thing out.

Here is some of my code:

```
'{datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(discord.Message.created_at)}'
```

I know this is wrong, because the discord.Message gives an object. How can I get an integer or a time out of it?

EDIT:

```
@client.command()
async def belep(message, url, felhasz, jelsz):
    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        for i in c:
            if i['Url'] == url:
                db = MySQLdb.connect(xxxxx)
                cursor = db.cursor()
                print(url + " " + felhasz + " " + jelsz)
                icode = i["InstituteCode"]
                headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'}
                payload = {'institute_code': f'{icode}', 'userName': f'{felhasz}', 'password': f'{jelsz}',
                           'grant_type': 'password', 'client_id': '919e0c1c-76a2-4646-a2fb-7085bbbf3c56'}

                response = requests.get(f"""https://{icode}.e-kreta.hu/idp/api/v1/Token""", headers=headers, data=payload)

                rjson = response.json()
                print()
                cursor.execute(
                    f"INSERT INTO token (mauthor, access_token, token_type, expires_in, refresh_token, msent, tokexpire) VALUES ('{message.author.id}', '{rjson['access_token']}', '{rjson['token_type']}', '{rjson['expires_in']}', '{rjson['refresh_token']}', '{datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(discord.Message.created_at)}','{datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(discord.Message.created_at)}')")
```

Comment: Show your whole code, otherwise we don't know where you get a message from

Comment: There you go. I have edited it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the moment you are calling the `discord.Message` class, but you actually wanna call the message object you get from the method. So just use `message` instead of `discord.Message`.

Note: `message.created_at` actually already returns a datetime object. [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.created_at)